# extend the current for PWM LED Control

Tags: gpio, python, led

i am using the raspberrypi to have 2 led's fade up and off.
My script works and its ready to go.

But i need to get my LED's brighter. Is there a way to extend the GPIO Current of the rasperry pi ?

Can i use something like that to realize it?
http://www.exp-tech.de/shields-module/raspberry-pi/pololu-drv8835-dual-motor-driver-kit-for-raspberry-pi-b
http://www.exp-tech.de/adafruit-12-channel-16-bit-pwm-led-driver-spi-interface-tlc59711

Comment: You may just need to resize (/correctly size) your resistor.

Comment: Please share the details of your connection setup.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything fancy.

You could just use a [ULN2003A](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/uln2003a-darlington-array?keyword=uln2003) to supply power to the LEDs and apply PWM to its inputs to control the brightness.

The maximum brightness should be set with an appropriate value for the LED current limiting resistor.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1Y_fYtRZnI) shows the Pi generating PWM to control the brightness of LEDs connected to a ULN2003A.  The persistence effect is generated by varying the PWM level.